# i can't trigger alert with an image on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the problem i have here is very annoying.What i wanna have is there is an empty box,i press a button and it places an image in that box,the code for that is:
HTML

```
<button id="rockb">choose rock!</button>
<div id="main">
<img id='pr' style="width: 500px;height: 600px;" src="">
</div>
```

As you can see the source of the image is nothing because i have to choose it

Jquery for choosing the source and placing it in the box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#rockb').click(function()
{
$('#mty').attr("src", "https://i.redd.it/2u0y0z5i12py.png");
});  </script>
```

just so you know there are multiple buttons so you can chose multiple images basiccaly the same as i show only other name and image link.

i want a script that says IF i press rockb it alerts 'paper' if i select paperb it says 'paper'
but i cant seem to make it work.here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (getElementById('#pr').attr('src') === 'https://i.redd.it/2u0y0z5i12py.png')
{
alert('euirhzeurhzu')
} 
</script>
```

Thank you for helping me and hopefully i explained it good!

Comment: Can't you include the alert in the click event?

Comment: no it needs to be like an if statement.my main goal isnt to get the alert its really difficult to explain but i need it in another if statement

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
$('#pr').attr("src", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQZtjprGwxPE5FVcY72h1MWxvVVSiW7RFHmJ6DZ9G1lf0YOr-vV");
if(true){
alert('euirhzeurhzu')
}
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="rockb">choose rock!</button>
<div id="main">
<img id='pr' style="width: 500px;height: 600px;" src="">
</div>
```